# How can I change the template loading order?

Tags: magento-1.9, template, core, design

As we all may know, when you set a template package at the admin it'll use it's default folder to provide the .xml and .phtml files. If the system doesn't find the necessary file, it will load it from 'base/default'. How can I change that? I want to add another folder for Magento to check before it goes looking for it at the base structure.

For example:

### current

- your_theme_package (if not found ->) base_package

### what I'm looking for

- your_theme_package (if not found ->) your_base_package (if not found ->) base_package

Answer (score 0):

You can check this excellent post by Alan Storm about infinite theme inheritance: http://alanstorm.com/magento_infinite_fallback_theme_xml

Regards,
Vincent

Comment: Vincent, your answer is almost right, but you should actually write down what I need to do in order to enable the theme inheritance (remember to point out that, the easy way, it's only possible after the 1.9 version) and then add the source at the bottom. Also, thanks!